# show picklist inside table header and make them working

Tags: visualforce

I have some no. type  records in first sec third  fields i have to color them acc to if positive then green , negative to red and zero as yelllow till it done now i want picklist in header that if i select red then all red values sort firstly red then others

class

```
public class colornumber{

    Public List<Account> AccList{get;set;}
    public List<selectoption>color{get;set;}
    public string col{get;set;}
    public colornumber(){
       List<Account> AccList=New list<Account>();
    } 
    public List<SelectOption> getdynamiclist() {

        List<SelectOption> color = new List<SelectOption>();

        color.add(new selectoption('RED','RED'));

        color.add(new selectoption('GREEN','GREEN'));

        color.add(new selectoption('YELLOW','YELLOW'));

        color.sort();

   return color;
}
public void  getlist(){

AccList=[Select Id,First__c,second__c,third__c from Account where First__c != null];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help actin support you can sort the account details as you select the different pick-list value

```
<apex:page controller="colornumber">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock id="main">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AccList}" var="a" >


                <apex:column value="{!a.First__c}" style="background-color:{!if(a.First__c>0,'green',if(a.First__c=0,'yellow','red'))}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:selectList value="{!firstSelected}" title="Choose a color" multiselect="false" size="1">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeInPicklist}" reRender="main">
                                 <apex:param value="First" assignTo="{!toSelect}" name="toSelect"/>
                            </apex:actionSupport>
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column value="{!a.second__c}" style="background-color:{!if(a.second__c>0,'green',if(a.second__c=0,'yellow','red'))}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:selectList value="{!secondSelected}" title="Choose a color" multiselect="false" size="1">
                              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeInPicklist}" reRender="main">
                                 <apex:param value="Second" assignTo="{!toSelect}" name="toSelect"/>
                            </apex:actionSupport>
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column value="{!a.third__c }" style="background-color:{!if(a.third__c >0,'green',if(a.third__c =0,'yellow','red'))}">
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:selectList value="{!thirdSelected}" title="Choose a color" multiselect="false" size="1">
                              <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeInPicklist}" reRender="main">
                                 <apex:param value="Third" assignTo="{!toSelect}" name="toSelect"/>
                            </apex:actionSupport>
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>


public with sharing class colornumber {
    Public list<Account> AccList{get;set;}
    public String firstSelected{get;set;}
    public String secondSelected{get;set;}
    public String thirdSelected{get;set;}
    public String toSelect{get;set;}

    public void changeInPicklist()
    {
        getlist();
    }

    public colornumber(){
        AccList=Database.query('Select Id,First__c,second__c,third__c from Account where First__c ' + getColorValue('GREEN'));
        AccList.addAll([Select Id,First__c,second__c,third__c from Account where id not in : AccList  ]);
        toSelect='';
    } 

    public List<SelectOption> getdynamiclist() {
        List<SelectOption> color = new List<SelectOption>();
        color.add(new selectoption('RED','RED'));
        color.add(new selectoption('GREEN','GREEN'));
        color.add(new selectoption('YELLOW','YELLOW'));
        color.sort();
        return color;
    }


    public void  getlist(){
        AccList=new list<account>();
        String Query='';
        if(toSelect=='First')
            Query='Select Id,First__c,second__c,third__c from Account where First__c ' + getColorValue(firstSelected) ;
        if(toSelect=='Second')
            Query='Select Id,First__c,second__c,third__c from Account where second__c ' + getColorValue(secondSelected) ;
        if(toSelect=='Third')
            Query='Select Id,First__c,second__c,third__c from Account where third__c ' + getColorValue(thirdSelected) ;

        AccList=Database.query(Query);
        AccList.addAll([Select Id,First__c,second__c,third__c from Account where id not in : AccList  ]);

    }

    public String getColorValue(String selectedColor)
    {
        if(selectedColor=='RED')
            return '< 0';
        if(selectedColor=='GREEN')
            return ' > 0';
        if(selectedColor=='YELLOW')
            return '= 0';

        return null;
    }

}
```

let me know if you don't get the code , Its all about logic how u can solve it.

Comment: thanks bro working pretty good only problem was in   if(toSelect=='First') if(toSelect=='second')

Comment: there should be use if, else if

Comment: check the spelling of **Second**   ,  Caps **S**

Comment: Your Welcome ..