# How to add same picklist to all of column header in page block table

Tags: visualforce

i have created a picklist in class

```
public List<SelectOption> getdynamiclist(){  
  List<SelectOption> color = new List<SelectOption>();  
    color.add(new selectoption('RED','RED'));  
        color.add(new selectoption('GREEN','GREEN'));  
        color.add(new selectoption('YELLOW','YELLOW'));  
        color.sort();  
        return color;  
    }
```

i want this two picklist at the place of first second third   and want them functional if i change color to green then all row data arranged firstly green then others. green is positive no. here yellow is zero and red is negative no.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In short you can put your pick list inside `<apex:Facet>`, it will execute only once inside `<apex:column>`

```
<apex:column styleClass="inBorder">
    <apex:facet name="header">  
      <apex:selectList  value="{!selected}" title="Choose a color"  multiselect="false" size="1">
         <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}"/>
       </apex:selectList >
     </apex:facet>
     <apex:outputText >your column value</apex:outputText>
 </apex:column>
```

try executing below code , hope your looking for this answer

```
   <apex:page controller="ColorController">
        <apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock title="Page Block Table">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Accounts}" var="a" styleClass="outBorder" width="550px">
                <apex:column styleClass="inBorder">
                    <apex:facet name="header">  
                       <apex:selectList  value="{!selected}" title="Choose a color"  multiselect="false" size="1">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}"/>
                        </apex:selectList >
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText >{!a.name}</apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>       
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>


    public class ColorController {
        public String selected{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> getdynamiclist(){  
      List<SelectOption> color = new List<SelectOption>();  
        color.add(new selectoption('RED','RED'));  
            color.add(new selectoption('GREEN','GREEN'));  
            color.add(new selectoption('YELLOW','YELLOW'));  
            color.sort();  
            return color;  
        }  

     public List<account> Accounts{ get {
        Accounts=[select id,name from account limit 10];
        return Accounts;
     } set; 
     }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks sir worked fine can u please give short info how to make picklist functional as now have 3 picklist at 3 rows header each should work for same row

Comment: Can you elaborate more.  Now you have made change to 3 column has 3 pick-list header right ?

Comment: i feel like basically you wanted achieve functionality like ,  you have three header  pick-list Called First, Second, and Third,  [related to your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184704/show-picklist-inside-table-header-and-make-them-working) , when you select first picklist you table should show all selected color at top row, this what you wanted achieve ?

Comment: yes sir if i will change 1st row header to yellow then it should show me all yellow on top , or if select green then it should show me green on top

Comment: yes sir , i want same bt it should also maintain column data

Comment: i have posted answer for you in  [related to your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184704/show-picklist-inside-table-header-and-make-them-working). please look at that one.